# Android : slide a window from right using animation

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

I have number of rows and on click of each row a respective window is opened.

// row click event

```
function function description() { return function(){

        var des =require('/ui/common/events/EventDescription');
        var w=des()
        w.open()
}

}
```

I want new window to open by sliding from the right to left.

tried this but no luck

```
function description() { return function(){

        var des =require('/ui/common/events/EventDescription');
        var w=des()

       var slide_it_left = Titanium.UI.createAnimation(); 
       slide_it_left.left = 0; 
       slide_it_left.duration = 300;
       win open(slide_it_left);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i had to learn: You can't animate `Ti.UI.Window` on android. This is not really documented because some animations should work. The most (useful) animations won't work.

So the sliding animation (setting top, left, right or bottom; width / height) don't work. If you want to use animations on Android you need to use them on Views.